# Multiple health-check endpoints in .NET Core 3.x

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there a way to configure multiple healthcheck endpoints in .NET Core 3.x?

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
};
```

This is what I have currently and I can't seem to configure another one on top of this.

Redirect in this case won't work as one of these will endpoints will behind a firewall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `HealthChecks` is a plain middleware,  you can always configure the pipeline in the same way as other normal middlewares.

For example:

```
//in a sequence way
app.UseHealthChecks("/path1");
app.UseHealthChecks("/path2");

// in a branch way: check a predicate function dynamically
app.MapWhen(
    ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/path3") || ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/path4"), 
    appBuilder=>{
        appBuilder.UseMiddleware<HealthCheckMiddleware>();
    }
);

// use endpoint routing
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health1");
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health2");
});
```

Answer (score 15):

Not sure what is your purpose for having multiple healthcheck endpoints.

If it is to support different "liveness" and "readiness" healthchecks, then the correct approach is indicated by Microsoft documentation "[Filter Health Checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1#filter-health-checks)".

In essence, it relies on adding tags to your health checks and then using those tags to route to the appropriate controller. You don't need to specify a healthcheck with "live" tag as you get the basic Http test out of the box.

In Startup.ConfigureServices()

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
        .AddCheck("SQLReady", () => HealthCheckResult.Degraded("SQL is degraded!"), tags: new[] { "ready" })
        .AddCheck("CacheReady", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy("Cache is healthy!"), tags: new[] { "ready" });
```

In Startup.Configure()

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/ready", new HealthCheckOptions()
    {
        Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("ready"),});

    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/live", new HealthCheckOptions()
    {
        Predicate = (_) => false});
});
```